# Comparing strings excluding parameters

Tags: ruby, string

I have two strings. One of them has parameters, which are unique names in curly braces. There could be any number of parameters, with any name.

1. I want to know if they match, excluding the parameterised parts. The parameterised sections can be multiple words and any length.
2. I want to save the parameterised parts into a hash with the key being the name of the parameter, not including the curly braces.

For example, with the following strings:

String 1:

```
This string is called Fred and Johnson and is very interesting
```

String 2:

```
This string is called {name} and is {rating} interesting
```

I would like to save:

```
parameters = {"name" => "Fred and Johnson", "rating" => "very"}
```

Any help on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: What happens when the files do not match in one line? What happens if one file has an inserted or a deleted line?

Comment: Forget that I mentioned two files. I am just comparing two strings at a time, same example as above. When the strings don't match I am simply returning false. If they do match I am capturing the parameters and returning true.

Comment: What happens if there are more than one way of matching? For example, String 2: `"{foo} and {bar}"`, String 1: `"A and B and C and D and E"`. What would `parameters` be?

Comment: Good question. It isn't possible to detect where the two parameters should be split without understanding the context. I will have to accept that there could be multiple solutions for the match. The method will need to keep finding possible matches, until it finds a match that satisfies the condition that the lines are equivalent, excluding the parametrised values. For your two strings, `foo => A, bar => B` would not satisfy that condition, even though it matches the regexp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
line1 = "This file is called Fred and Johnson and is very interesting"
line2 = "This file is called {name} and is {rating} interesting"

def match_lines(line1, line2)
  line2_re_code = Regexp.escape(line2).gsub(/\\{(.+?)\\}/, '(?<\1>.+?)')
  line2_re = Regexp.new("^#{line2_re_code}$")
  if match = line2_re.match(line1)
    hash = Hash[match.names.map { |name| [name, match[name]] }]
    puts hash.inspect
  else
    puts "No match"
  end
end

match_lines(line1, line2)
# => { "name" => "Fred and Johnson", "rating" => "very" }
match_lines(line1, "foo")
# => No match
match_lines("foo", line2)
# => No match
```

EDIT: added anchors. Also, explanation:

We will make a regexp from the pattern line, by first escaping special regexp characters, which gives this:

```
'This\ file\ is\ called\ \{name\}\ and\ is\ \{rating\}\ interesting'
```

Then we turn the placeholders into Oniguruma named captures:

```
'This\ file\ is\ called\ (?<name>.+?)\ and\ is\ (?<rating>.+?)\ interesting'
```

and then add anchors and make a regexp from it, to make sure `line1` doesn't have stuff in front or dangling at the end:

```
/^This\ file\ is\ called\ (?<name>.+?)\ and\ is\ (?<rating>.+?)\ interesting$/
```

EDIT2: `Regexp#match` will return `nil` if the match fails, or a `MatchData` object; you can use `MatchData#[]` to access the individual placeholder values. You can use `MatchData#names` to see which placeholders were present.

EDIT3: Oops... As said in comments, `names` should have been `match.names`.

Comment: Very interesting, but I'm not sure the problem is well-defined. For example, if `line1 = "This file is called Fred and is Johnson and is very interesting"`, then `match_lines(line1, line2) #=>  Name: Fred, rating: Johnson and is very`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Of course, that is one of the possible ways to match that sentence. *shrug*

Comment: @Jordan: I am not escaping spaces. `Regexp#escape` is. And space is totally a special character in Oniguruma regexp if you turn on the `x` option; `Regexp#escape` can't know if it will be on or not, and if not, backslash-space is equivalent to space, so there is no harm.

Comment: Hi Amadan, thanks for helping. In your solution above, the MatchData that is returned is the whole line 1, not the extracted place holders. `line2_re.match(line1) {|m| puts m} => This file is called Fred and Johnson and is very interesting`. Because of this, `match[name] => {}`. I am terrible with regexp which is why I asked for help, so I cant tell if there is an issue with it `line2_re.to_s => (?-mix:^This\ file\ is\ called\ (?<name>.+?)\ and\ is\ (?<rating>.+?)\ interesting$)`

Comment: `puts m` will convert `m` to a string; `m.to_s` is giving the full match text. `m[name]` is an error unless `name` is a defined variable. `m["name"]` cannot be a hash under any circumstances. So something went wrong in your implementation, and in your response too. The regexp is correct. If you run my code without any modification, do you get the outputs that I posted in comment lines? (Note that it relies on Oniguruma engine, which is only available from Ruby 1.9; you should not be using 1.8, as it is end-of-lifed.)

Comment: I had another look and I see what I did wrong. I declared an empty array for `names` as it didn't exist in your example. Obviously that array never got populated which is why I was getting blank results. What would be the simplest way for me to extract the name of the placeholders from the string?

Comment: Last sentence of the answer: `match.names`.

Comment: Awesome. There was no `match.names` in the answer currently, but changing `names.map` to `match.names.map` works perfectly! Thanks for all the help!